# Python 3 / PyQt 5 - ImportError: Undefined Symbol

Tags: pyqt5, python-3.5, importerror

I was making a QSS Theme Preview Program in PyQt 5. But, It suddenly stoppped working:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "core.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtCore import *
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.so: undefined symbol: PySlice_AdjustIndices
```

I removed and re-installed `qt5-default`, `python3-pyqt5`, and `python3-sip`, but the error still occurs.

I am using `Lubuntu 16.04` LTS (Xenial Xerus) On An `Acer Chromebook R11` C738T using Crouton and `Python 3.5.1-3` and `PyQt 5.11.2`. (I'm pretty sure that the version isn't the problem; other people had the same problem with different Python and PyQt versions)

P.S. Some people say that I need Python 3.6+, but when I run `sudo apt install python3`, `apt` says `python3 is already the newest version (3.5.1-3)`. Plus, I get error when I try to build it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I fixed it by upgrading to python 3.6, sorry I can't dig deeper.

I put the steps to update the python from 3.5 to 3.6, in my case I work in Linux mint, but the steps should be the same.

First the installation.

1. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6
2. sudo apt update
3. sudo apt-get install python3.6

Now the configuration (To make the system take version 3.6 by default)

**!!!WARNING, depending on the version of Linux|distribution, system problems may be caused if you make default another python version!!!**

1. sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.5 1
2. sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.6 2
3. update-alternatives --list python3
4. sudo update-alternatives --config python3

Then install the pip3 again

1. wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
2. sudo python3 get-pip.py

I hope it helps you, I'm sorry I can't tell you the cause of the problem, I hope someone tells us, for now it seems to be a PyQt5 bug with this version.

Anyway, good luck.

Comment: BTW, `add-apt-repository` wasn't installed on my instance, to fix, go to http://lifeonubuntu.com/ubuntu-missing-add-apt-repository-command/.

Comment: Works on Debian Minimal